# How can I have a C library modify a structure I passed via ctypes?

Tags: python, c, ctypes

Here's my C code:

```
typedef struct {
    int a;
} A;

__declspec(dllexport) A new_a(int x) {
    A a = {x};
    return a;
}

__declspec(dllexport) void change(A a) { a.a++; }

__declspec(dllexport) int get_a(A a) { return a.a; }
```

I compiled it into a MODULE DLL and in Python I did this:

```
import ctypes

lib = ctypes.windll.LoadLibrary('C:\\Users\\avishah\\CLionProjects\\Math\\lib\\libpythonclass2.dll')

a = lib.new_a(10)
print(lib.get_a(a), type(a))  # gives 10, says type of a is 'int'
lib.change(a)  # doesn't change value
print(lib.get_a(a))  # still shows 10
```

I'm sure I have to use pointers in the C code, but it usually gives me this error:

```
OSError: exception: access violation reading 0x000000000000000A
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your code.

The first is that you did not specify the type signature for the FFI function you imported. You need to create a type definition for your structure, and assign argument and return types to the imported functions.

```python
import ctypes

lib = ctypes.windll.LoadLibrary(r'C:\Users\avishah\CLionProjects\Math\lib\libpythonclass2.dll')

class A(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = (
        ('a', ctypes.c_int),
    )

new_a = lib.new_a
new_a.restype = A
new_a.argtypes = (ctypes.c_int,)

change = lib.change
change.restype = None
change.argtypes = (A,)

get_a = lib.get_a
get_a.restype = ctypes.c_int
get_a.argtypes = (A,)
```

The second is that the `change` function receives the structure by value. In other words, the function operates on a copy of the structure received on the argument list, which means the copy held by the caller will never be modified. To actually modify the structure, you need to pass a pointer:

```c
__declspec(dllexport) void change(A *a) { a->a++; }
```

```python
change = lib.change
change.restype = None
change.argtypes = (ctypes.POINTER(A),)
```

Now your code should behave as you expect:

```python
a = new_a(10)
print(get_a(a), type(a))   # should print 10 <class '__main__.A'>
change(ctypes.byref(a))    # equivalent C: change(&a);
print(get_a(a))            # should print 11
```

Comment: Thanks! It really helps... I struggle with this bit a lot because most people use Linux for examples and all this is not there. One question... does it actually help on memory usage because it's using a pointer, or does it still internally create a copy?

Comment: Linux requires the same type declarations, there isn’t actually a difference here between platforms. Given that the structure is just a single `int`, going through a pointer may technically *increase* memory usage here (though not by very much). As the structure grows, though, passing it as a pointer is going to pay off more in terms of memory usage. Either way, there is no copying: the whole point of passing a pointer as an argument is to allow the callee to operate on the exact same object the caller has instead of a copy.